# RecycleView & CardView Items, Margins and Centering

Tags: java, android

I have created a hand of cards, currently they are ordering from the left most screen to right with a horizontal scroll.

I want to basically center the items to the parent layout.

In my `activity.xml`
I have a `LinearLayout` which has a matching width to parent

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/computer_info"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/computer_info"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp">
```

Inside this i have my recycler viewer which has a width of matching parent

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Now in my item.xml which is my carview it looks like this

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:cardElevation="0dp">

    <!--Text View over Card View-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ace_of_spades">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

When i go into the display mode of the item.xml, it shows its center on the screen.

But when i run the game it doesnt apply any change.

The cards below Computer Hand is what i am trying to change.

[image: My Game View]

---

**EDIT:**

After changing my RecyclerView `layout_width` to `wrap content`, it centers perfectly. but now it looks like this:

[image: Image Is here]

How would i go about making it so the cards are pretty close together and not separated so far

Comment: Centering my relative layout also does nothing.

Comment: But when i change the RecyclerView width to wrapcontent, it seems to center fine..